# Spring Webflow + MVC resources mapping

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, primefaces, mapping, spring-webflow

I'm trying to make a sample project using spring mvc, webflow and primefaces.
Here is my deployment descriptor (web.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestMVC</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/app/testClasses</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- Context parameters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jExposeWebAppRoot</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>


      <!-- Logging -->    
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <!-- Appcontext listener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
      <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
      <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
      <param-value>1</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

MVC servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:webflow-config="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">


    <bean id="facesContextListener" class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />
    <webflow-config:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow-config:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow-config:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        </webflow-config:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow-config:flow-executor>

    <faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices"/>

    <webflow-config:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows">
        <webflow-config:flow-location-pattern value="/**/flow.xml"/>
    </webflow-config:flow-registry>

    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/primefaces/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo/" mapping="/javax.faces.resource/**"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.test.controller" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
        <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.faces.mvc.JsfView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".xhtml" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.JsfFlowHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" p:basenames="WEB-INF/i18n/messages,WEB-INF/i18n/application" p:fallbackToSystemLocale="false" />
</beans>
```

The question I have - is it right to make such mappings:

```
<mvc:resources location="/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/primefaces/, classpath:/META-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo/" mapping="/javax.faces.resource/**"/>
```

in the MVC servlet context or I'm doing something wrong? In the examples from the book "Pro SPRING 3" there's no such mapping, but if I remove it, I will receive an errors like no mapping found for ".../javax.faces.resource/theme.css" in DispatcherServlet and so on.
I think my way to add mappings is wrong because I don't see images from primefaces-aristo/images anyway.

Versions of libraries are:
Spring faces and webflow: 2.3.0.RELEASE
Spring webmvc: 3.2.3.RELEASE
Primefaces: 4.0
jsf-api and jsf-impl: 2.0.11

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I found an answer myself. The way I used is wrong, tag mvc:resources is used for local resources mapping and to map JSF resources one needs to add

```
<faces:resources/>
```

into mvc servlet context.

Answer (score 0):

```
used pom.xml

   <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-js</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>



and 

     <mvc:resources mapping="/web-resources/**/" location="/"/>
```